# How can I make a recursive Promise call to be the return for a reduce in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a recursive `Promise` call inside a `reduce` in JS. The goal for my system here is to make n big calls for each item in the array that `reduce` plays with, then, if, inside that `reduce` that big call decides it needs n smaller calls before it gets back to the big ones, then the `reduce` shouldn't skip to the next item, just wait for it to finish.

My current code is:

```
function download_preliminary_files_1() {
    let demo_schema_download = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
        localized_data.ajax_url,
        {
            'ajax_action': 'download_demo_file_schema',
            'ajax_nonce': localized_data.ajax_nonce,
            'backend': {
                'data_handle': 'download_demo_file_schema_data',
                'data':
                    {
                        'demo_handle' : 'demo-2',
                    }
            }
        }
    );

    let import_files_download = demo_schema_download.call().then(function() {
        fake_data.steps_to_import.reduce(function(previous_promise, next_step_identifier) {
            return previous_promise.then(function() {
                let file_download = download_demo_file({
                    'demo_handle' : 'demo-2',
                    'step' : next_step_identifier
                }).call();

                file_download.then(function(response) {
                    /**
                     * Here, if I detect that response.remaining_number_of_files > 0, I should start
                     * a chain that keeps calling `download_demo_file` with new parameters.
                     *
                     * Then, when this chain is done, resume the normal reduce behavior.
                     */
                });
            });
        }, Promise.resolve())
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log( 'Got this error:' + error);
    });

    return import_files_download;
}
```

Where `Base_Ajax_Requester` is a helper class that handles AJAX requests and returns a `Promise` when it's done so code could be written around it.

My `fake_data` is:

```
let fake_data = {
    'demo_handle' : 'demo-2',
    'steps_to_import' : [ 'elementor-hf','post', 'nav_menu' ]
}
```

As you can see `fake_data.steps_to_import.reduce(..` will go through these 3 values, for each of them call `download_demo_file`, wait for it to finish, then proceed to the next. We could say that I'd like to, between `elementor-hf` and `post` to have n smaller calls.

The initial call to `download_demo_file` is seen up there, here's what will always come back from the back-end:

```
{
    'message' : '...',
    'file_number' : 1, //Which -n.xml file has been downloaded where n is this number.
    'remaining_number_of_files' : 1 //Calculates, based on what file was downloaded how many files are left. The system knows internally how many files it has to download.
}
```

The retry call, again, with `download_demo_file` would look like:

```
{
    'demo_handle' : 'demo-2',
    'step' : next_step_identifier,
    'file_counter' : 2 //Dynamic. This will signal that it needs to now download file-2.xml.
}
```

...and so on, until the back-end sends `remaining_number_of_files : 0`, then it all stops because there are no more files to download and it can skip to the next big call.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside each `reduce` callback, I'd make a function that calls `download_demo_file` (with a changing `file_counter`), and after that Promise resolves, recursively returns a call of itself if `remaining_number_of_files > 0`. This will mean that `getProm()` will continually call itself until the `remaining_number_of_files > 0` condition is not fulfilled anymore, and that only after that will the whole Promise for that particular `reduce` iteration resolve.

```
let import_files_download = demo_schema_download.call().then(function() {
  fake_data.steps_to_import.reduce(function(previous_promise, step) {
    let file_counter = 1;
    return previous_promise.then(function() {
      const getProm = () => download_demo_file({
        demo_handle: 'demo-2',
        step,
        file_counter
      }).call()
        .then((response) => {
          file_counter++;
          return response.remaining_number_of_files > 0
            ? getProm()
            : response
        });
      return getProm();
    });
  }, Promise.resolve())
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Got this error:' + error);
});
```

The code would probably be a *lot* easier to read and understand with `async`/`await`, though:

```
await demo_schema_download.call();
const import_files_download = [];
for (const step of fake_data.steps_to_import) {
  let response;
  let file_counter = 1;
  do {
    response = await download_demo_file({
      demo_handle: 'demo-2',
      step,
      file_counter
    }).call();
    file_counter++;
  } while (response.remaining_number_of_files > 0);
  import_files_download.push(response); // is this needed?
}
return import_files_download; // is this needed?
```

Catch in the consumer of the async function.

Comment: I cannot use `async/await` due to compatibility restraints and polyfills being unreliable.

Comment: Also, your code theoretically works, but it doesn't as of now because I'm not passing the new parameters (so the system can't tell that the new flag `file_counter` has appeared. Can you please update the code and I know it's a lot to ask but I promise this will be put to good use - can you explain a bit what's going on?

Comment: Should be simple enough, just keep track of a `file_counter` which gets incremented

Comment: Certainly! But at the `?  getProm()` if I pass this new parameter, well, nothing happens. Thoughts?

Comment: Since `file_counter` is in the outer scope (of the `.reduce` callback), there shouldn't be any need to pass a `file_counter` parameter (though I guess you could do so if you want) - it gets incremented inside the `.call()`'s `.then`, and is visible to the `download_demo_file` as well

Comment: It looks like you're using ES6 - if you're not using Babel, or if you're already targeting ES6+ environments, you can use `await` by transpiling *without* `regeneratorRuntime`, if that's the problem. The transformation is [relatively simple](https://babeljs.io/repl/) from an `async` function to a generator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195424/discussion-between-coolpasta-and-certainperformance).